# Not able to create tables by using batch cmd

Tags: html, batch-file

I want to add gif files into a TABLE (HTML file) by using batch command, I am facing problem with below lines

```
set "table_start=^<table border='1'>"
set "table_one=^<tr^>^<th^>^Name^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
```

when i edit the html file in notepad i don't see tags for table border and row one. Below is the complete code, can somebody help me on this?

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file_start=^<title^>^HTML Table Header GIRI^</title^>"
set "table_start=^<table border='1'>"
set "row_one=^<tr^>^<th^>^Name^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
set "image_start=^<tr^>^<th^>^<IMG SRC=""
set ^"image_end="^>^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
set "table_end=^</table^>"
set "file_end=^</BODY^>^</HTML^>"
set "file_name=Index.html"

>"%file_name%"  ( echo %USERNAME% %DATE%  %TIME%
echo %file_start%
for %%I in (*.gif) do echo %image_start%%%~fI%image_end% 

echo %file_end%
)

start %file_name%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never echoed table_start, row_one, or table_end to file_name. Additionally, you missed one escape character at the end of table_start. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file_start=^<title^>^HTML Table Header GIRI^</title^>"
set "table_start=^<table border='1'^>"
set "row_one=^<tr^>^<th^>^Name^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
set "image_start=^<tr^>^<th^>^<IMG SRC=""
set ^"image_end="^>^</th^>^<th^>^Remarks^</th^>^</tr^>"
set "table_end=^</table^>"
set "file_end=^</BODY^>^</HTML^>"
set "file_name=Index.html"

>"%file_name%"  ( echo %USERNAME% %DATE%  %TIME%
echo %file_start%
echo %table_start%
echo %row_one%
for %%I in (*.gif) do echo %image_start%%%~fI%image_end% 
echo %table_end%

echo %file_end%
)
```

Comment: If i use %%~fI in "FOR" command it returns with this format of file path "C:\Users\Girish\Pictures\03\302.jpg". What command should i use to get file path in this format "file:///C:/Users/Girish/Pictures/03/test/302.jpg" ???